# Why is my fetch request returning "...doesn't work without JavaScript enabled..."?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, fetch-api

I have a sample project at https://github.com/ericg-vue-questions/leaflet-test/tree/fetch-method
(fetch-method branch)

The relevant code is in [LeafletTest.vue](https://github.com/ericg-vue-questions/leaflet-test/blob/fetch-method/src/components/LeafletTest.vue) and is

```
<template>
  <img src="./TheCloud.svg" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Map",

  data() {
    this.loadSVGIcon();
    return {}
  },

  methods: {
    async loadSVGIcon() {
      const response = await fetch( "./TheCloud.svg" );
      const svgSrc = await response.text();
      console.log( "loadSVGIcon", response );
      console.log( "loadSVGIcon", svgSrc );
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

As I understand it, because I can get the svg to display with the <img ... /> tag, I should be able to use a fetch request to obtain the svg source.

However, when I do this, the text I get back is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <title>leaflet-test</title>
  <link href="/js/app.js" rel="preload" as="script"><link href="/js/chunk-vendors.js" rel="preload" as="script"></head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but leaflet-test doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/chunk-vendors.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

which is weird.

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to change so I can get the SVG source?

Comment: "./TheCloud.svg" file doesn't exist at the time when the app runs. You can use files from "public" like that. For "src", you need to import them as modules

Comment: Are you suggesting that if I move TheCloud.svg to a different folder that it would work? If so, exactly where should I move it to?

Comment: It's called `public`. It's in the root of your repo.

Comment: bingo. If you wanted to write that up as the answer, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `fetch( "./TheCloud.svg" )` to work, it should be static file, which is located in `/public` folder in Vue CLI projects. Also relative URL paths may give problems, while absolute paths like `fetch( "/TheCloud.svg" )` are unambiguous.

Otherwise it can be bundled and imported from `/src`:

```
const svgSrc = await import("./TheCloud.svg");
```

or

```
import svgSrc from "./TheCloud.svg";
```

The actual content of imported non-JS files like images depends on project configuration.

Comment: The fetch-method branch has been updated to implement this solution